# How to hide view.xml fields group in Account module with attr

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am using openerp version 7 and need to hide  below section from existing module. I tried with many ways but still unable to do that.please advice me to sort out this (line 933 in account module) is there any restrictions in core modules or something missing to me ?

```
<group string="Refunds" attrs="{'invisible':[('active','=',True)]}">
<field name="account_paid_id" domain="[('type','&lt;&gt;','view'),('type','&lt;&gt;','consolidation')]"/>
<field name="account_analytic_paid_id" domain="[('type','&lt;&gt;','view'), ('company_id', '=', company_id), ('parent_id', '&lt;&gt;', False)]" groups="analytic.group_analytic_accounting"/>

<field name="ref_base_code_id"/>
<field name="ref_base_sign"/>
<field name="ref_tax_code_id"/>
<field name="ref_tax_sign"/>
</group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attrs syntax is right except value given in domain. You are giving 'true' which will be treated as a string not boolean.

Try this:

`<group string="Refunds" attrs="{'invisible':[('active','!=',True)]}">`

Comment: thanks arya.but its not worked for me 
i seperately add invisible ="1" for some fields.those are also not worked.after changes done, need to restart server & upgrade modules is enough ?

Comment: i changed acount_view.xml line 1042 only.after upgrade also no result & its same

Comment: I see the result from Accounting->Configuration->Taxes->Taxes
hope my editing lines & result page is equal or it affect to another form ?

Comment: Make sure that changes you have made is really a view of tax or not? Because on account_view.xml: 1042 belongs to `account.move.line` form view. In your question you mentioned that you want to change line: 933.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27456/discussion-between-priyan-rockz-and-arya)